# Vertical GrayScale Plot

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to make a grayscale plot like the one shown below, except I'd like it to plot vertically.

[image]

ArrayPlot seems to only plot horizontally.  Is there a way to make it plot vertically or is there another function more suitable?

```
ArrayPlot[{Table[Log[x], {x, 1/256, 1, 1/256}]}, AspectRatio -> .08, 
 Frame -> False]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) on your list.

```
ArrayPlot[Transpose@{Table[Log[x], {x, 1/256, 1, 1/256}]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/.08, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Equivalently, change to `Table[{Log[x]}, {x, 1/256, 1, 1/256}]`.